# How to prepend lines to git command output

Tags: bash, shell, git, tty

This is part of a larger script but I distilled the problem down to this:

```
cm_safe(){
   git push | while read line; do
    echo "cm safe push: $line"
   done;
}
```

I want to prepend git output, so it would look like:

> cm safe push: Everything up-to-date

but instead I just get:

> Everything up-to-date

Is git writing to the tty or something directly? I dunno what's going on.

Comment: I did `git push --help` and I don't see an option on where to send stdout/stderr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git push` writes to stderr so you would have to redirect that to stdout in order for it to be sent over the pipeline:

```
cm_safe(){
   git push 2>&1 | while IFS= read -r line; do
     echo "cm safe push: $line"
   done
}
```

Alternatively you could do:

```
git push |& while IFS= read -r line; do
```

I recommend reading [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/237982) for more information.

Comment: ahhh git by default writes to stderr, now that is messed up, thanks

Comment: @AlexChannelmeter it's entirely standard practice for tools to write their status messages to stderr.

Answer (score 2):

As you already know now, `git push`s output is going to stderr, not stdout. Beyond that, you should always use `while IFS= read -r line` to read lines of input using the shell unless you have a very specific reason to drop either the `IFS=` or the `-r`. It's like always quoting your shell variables - it's something you remove when you have to, not something you add when you have to.

FWIW I'd use:

```
cm_safe() { git push 2>&1 | awk '{print "cm safe push:", $0}'; }
```

or:

```
cm_safe() { git push 2>&1 | sed 's/^/cm safe push: /'; }
```

anyway though given that [using a shell loop to process text is considered bad practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219).

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work, but I don't know why:

```
 git push &> /dev/stdout
```

did it force git to send it's stdout/stderr to the terminal stdout? I don't get it

Comment: `&>` will redirect both stdout and stderr, and you are redirecting them both into stdout so it's essentially the same as `2>&1`

Comment: yes but that's not the issue - the issue was git was writing stdio to something other than stdout/stderr

Comment: No the issue is that is writes to stderr.

Comment: yes you're right, ty appreciate it